# Appengine - The fast way to call others module in the same project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have some appengine modules in my project.

I am building a "Cloud Endpoints" that will works like a API Gateway. Both in them same project.

The endpoints will receive a request and forward to another appengine module, so, when the module process the request, the endpoints will return the response to frontend.
The main reponsibility this API Gateway will be validate permissions and log informations.
The frontend sends: GET,PUT and POST methods.

I read about URLFetch to do it.

I would like to know, Is it fast to use URLFetch to to do it?

Should I use other framework to to id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on App Engine, external requests should use URL fetch regardless of if you use it directly or use your language level networking primitives. It should be relatively fast, though you should benchmark this for yourself to see if it's an acceptable latency.